# "incompatible types when initializing type" after initializing an struct with an union inside

Tags: c, data-structures, types

After implementing the data structure suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273904/appropriate-data-structure-for-a-list-of-items-with-general-and-specific-propert), I decided to fill it with some test values.

The code is

```
typedef enum {car, gun, bullet} itemtype;

typedef struct bullettype {
    unsigned short velocity;
    unsigned short kinetic_energy;
} Bullet;

typedef struct cartype {
    unsigned short maxspeed;
} Car;

typedef enum {handgun, shotgun, machinegun} weapontype;

typedef struct firearmtype {
    weapontype type;
    char capacity;
} Firearm;

typedef struct gameitem {
    itemtype type;
    char* name;
    unsigned short bulk; 
    unsigned short weight;
    union {
        Car c;
        Bullet b;
        Firearm f;
    };
} Item;

int main() {
    Item *objects = malloc(50 *sizeof(Item));
    objects[0] = (Item) {gun, "a gun", 500, 5000, (Firearm) {handgun, 10}};
    objects[1] = (Item) {car, "a car", 3500, 4000, (Car) {200}};
    objects[2] = (Item) {bullet, "a bullet", 200, 3000, (Bullet) {300, 5000}};
    free(objects);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile it, I get

```
itemlisttest.c:40:2: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘short unsigned int’ using type ‘Firearm’
itemlisttest.c:42:3: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘short unsigned int’ using type ‘Bullet’
```

Which means the `car` item is working fine. And it's listed first in the union inside the struct. So I decided to swap Car and Bullet in the union like this

```
union {
    Bullet b;
    Car c;
    Firearm f;
};
```

And the compiler error is now

```
itemlisttest.c:40:2: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘short unsigned int’ using type ‘Firearm’
itemlisttest.c:41:2: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘short unsigned int’ using type ‘Car’
```

Does this have to do with the way I'm initializing the structs? I'm doing it like that because it will be a long list and 1000 `object[a].name = "name"` lines don't look pretty at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pre-C99 C you could initialize only the first member of the union. However, starting with C99 if you provide a name for the union member, you could use C99 feature of designated initializers:

```
typedef struct gameitem {
    itemtype type;
    char* name;
    unsigned short bulk;
    unsigned short weight;
    union {
        Car c;
        Bullet b;
        Firearm f;
    }u;
} Item;

objects[0] = (Item) {gun, "a gun", 500, 5000, .u.f=(Firearm) {handgun, 10}};
objects[1] = (Item) {car, "a car", 3500, 4000, .u.c=(Car) {200}};
objects[2] = (Item) {bullet, "a bullet", 200, 3000, .u.b=(Bullet) {300, 5000}};
```

Comment: It works now, thanks. The original code doesn't seem to work if being compiled as C99, but your code works even if it's not compiled as C99.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a name for the union field:

```
union {
    Bullet b;
    Car c;
    Firearm f;
} field_name_in_gameitem_struct;
```

Comment: Tried giving a name to the union but it still gives the same error. What if initializing unions inside structs is not supposed to be done like that?